# Inner Query For Oracle is not working?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, subquery

I have 2 tables table1 and table2.  I want fetch data from two tables. the query is

```
SELECT tb2.tdn
     ,tb2.nrn
     ,tb2.id
     ,tb2.dat
     ,tb2.mcheck
     ,tb2.info
     ,tb2.edrf
     , (SELECT count(*) 
        from table1 tb1
        where tb1.id = 'ftam' 
        and tb1.tdn =  tb2.tdn 
        and (tb1.display = 'Y' OR tb1.display = 'y') ) as history 
from (select rownum rnum 
             ,table2.* 
      FROM  (SELECT * 
             FROM table2 
             WHERE id = 'ftam' 
             and (display = 'Y' OR display = 'y') 
             ORDER BY dat DESC ) table2 tb2 
     where  rownum <= 50 )
WHERE rnum >  0
```

showing

```
SQL Error [907] [42000]: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis  
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

What is wrong with query?  I have implemented it in MySQL, but when I changed query to Oracle it is showing the error.

Thanks

Comment: You forget to name query as tb2 after "<= 50 )"

Comment: The query its not written well.

Comment: when i use
SELECT tb2.tdn,tb2.nrn,tb2.id,tb2.dat,tb2.mcheck,tb2.info,tb2.edrf ,(select count(*) from table1 tb1 where tb1.id = 'ftam' and tb1.tdn =  tb2.tdn and (tb1.display = 'Y' OR tb1.display = 'y') ) as history 
from table2 tb2  its working

Comment: (select rownum rnum ,table2.* FROM  (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = 'ftam' and (display = 'Y' OR display = 'y') 
       ORDER BY dat DESC ) table2 tb2 where  rownum <= 
        50 ) WHERE rnum >  0

problem is with this statement

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17216/alias-names-and-two-table-query-problems

i changed it from here

Comment: @Mureinik - what exactly do you mean by "doesn't play nice"?

Comment: @Mureinik: of course Oracle plays "nice" with scalar queries in the select list. Why do you think it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altering the posting layout for clarity reveals that this line is the immediate problem:

```
ORDER BY dat DESC ) table2 tb2
```

You need one alias, not two.  So it should be

```
ORDER BY dat DESC )  table2
```

You also need to put an alias on the outer nested query:

```
(select rownum rnum 
             ,table2.* 
      FROM  (SELECT * 
             FROM table2 
             WHERE id = 'ftam' 
             and (display = 'Y' OR display = 'y') 
             ORDER BY dat DESC ) table2
     where  rownum <= 50 ) tb2
```

Comment: @vineeth.soman - if this answer solved your problem, please accept it.  This helps future seekers who find this thread in their search results.

Answer (score -1):

Your query needs a lot of improvement , if you tell us what are your trying to do, we can maybe help you with building the query.

In your query id is a character , its better to be number . you add condition ='y' or ='Y' , you can added lower/upper fuction.

this a suggestion to fix your query .

```
   select rownum rnum, table2.*
     FROM table2
   WHERE id = 'ftam'
   and lower(display) = 'Y' and rownum <= 50
   ORDER BY dat DESC
```

Comment: This won't fix the syntax error the OP gets.  Also, while it may be neater it would disable the use of an index on `display`.  Which might not matter but it could.

Comment: @APC I suggest to the user to modify its select , because its badly writen, I do agree that you spot the error, but I gave an advice to improve its query.